# Multple accounts on one PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn

I just purchased a new PS4 and found out that PlayStation Plus is required for online gameplay. My PS4 is shared with someone else at home so I want to ask if one PlayStation Plus subscription can be shared between multiple PSN accounts on the same machine? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

They cannot. A PS Plus subscription can only be applied on a single account at a time and cannot be shared between multiple accounts.